# Best way to bind jquery to vue templates with v-if divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, dynamic, vue-component

New to vue, and pretty weak in front-end dev.  I'm trying to create a simple score card app and when the v-if changes the div displayed on the page, the jquery isn't bound to the new elements. For example in the template I have something like:

```
        <div v-if="get_game_state() === 'NEW'">
            <h3>Select Number of Players</h3>
            <button id='one_player' class="btn btn-success">1</button>
            <button id='two_players' class="btn btn-success">2</button>
            <button id='three_players' class="btn btn-success">3</button>
            <button id='four_players' class="btn btn-success">4</button>
            <button id='five_players' class="btn btn-success">5</button>
            <button id='six_players' class="btn btn-success">6</button>
        </div>
        <div v-else-if="get_game_state() === 'PLAYER_SETUP'">
            <div v-for="index in number_of_players" :key="index">
                Enter Player {{ index }}'s Name:
                <input type="text" :id='player_id(index)'>
            </div>
            <button id="test_submit_names" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

So when the game state changes they players can enter their names, however the submit button isn't working, since the submit button's click method is setup in the vue's "mounted" phase of the view.

```
       mounted() {

            var ref = this;

            $('#one_player').click(function() {
                ref.number_of_players = 1;
                ref.game_state = "PLAYER_SETUP";
            }); 

            ...

            $('#test_submit_names').click(function() {
                //alert(ref.number_of_players);
                //for (i = 0; i < ref.number_of_players; i++) {
                //     ref.players[i] = $('#player_'+ i).val();
                // }
                ref.game_state = "GAME_SELECTION";
            });

            ...
        },
```

What's the best way to handle something like this.  Should I load everything in the template and use hidden/show instead of vue v-if statements?  Or how do you handle dynamic vue elements with jquery?

Comment: You don't.  You use the vue bindings.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: @Taplar easy enough, thank you!